# expected {&unknown}, found String

Tags: rust

I can't compare guess with word and it throws me an expected {&unknown}, found String. error

```
fn main() {
    let mut guess = String::new();
    let word: String = String::from("Hello, world");

    for x in 1..10 {
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut guess)
            .except("failed to read line");

        println!("{}", guess.eq(word)); //error is in this line
    }

    println!("Game is over");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must borrow `word` when you are comparing to it. So write `guess.eq(&word)`. But this is equivalent to `guess == word`, so I would recommend this instead.

Also when you are reading line the endline character `'\n'` will also be added to `guess`, so you should probably use `guess.trim()` before compering to discard leading and trailing whitespaces.